# Retrieving the base type(s) from a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Is it possible to somehow get the base of a certain class so that it could be passed up a template chain like so (pseudo code)

```
template<typename base>
class first
{
    template_taking_base<base>* member;
}

template<typename derived>
class second: public first< function_giving_me_base_of_derived >
{
    derived* get( string s ) { dynamic_cast<derived>( member->get_base( s ) ); }
}
```

In order to avoid

```
template<typename base, typename derived>
class second: public first<base>
{
  //...
}
```

Why is this necessary?

I have two different types of resources, those that are in main memory, and those that are in gpu memory, currently this looks something like:

```
         basic_resource
         /           \
        /             \
   cpu_resource   gpu_resource
       |               |
   many_derived    many_derived
```

I also have handles to these resources. The idea is that you'd have

```
handle<image> someimage("blah.bmp")
image the_image = someimage.get();
```

Where the get function asks a cache to get the resource. The cache returns cpu_resource or gpu_resource while the handle dynamic casts it to the templated resource ( in the above case image ).

Cache itself is a template

```
template<typename resource_base>
class cache
{
public:
//...
   resource_base* get_resource( string name )
private:
//...
}
```

Where resource base should be one of either cpu_resource or gpu_resource, with the appropriate specializations in various member functions of the cache template.

So the handle, keeping a pointer to a cache, has to know the base type of the resource it is a handle for.

Specifically

```
template<typename resource_type>
class handle
{
  string name;
  cache< /*need the base of resource_type here*/ >* cache

  resource_type* get( void ) { dynamic_cast<resource_type>( cache->get( name ) ); }
}
```

I tried to generalize the problem so I could get an answer more quickly but that didn't work so maybe this will. If you need more specifics please ask.

Comment: Can you post a small usage example of how and where this would be necessary?

Comment: The question/examples/need are not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Any **derived** class is already of type **base** , So why would you want to do this ?

If you must you can do something like this

```
class A
{   
public:
    A()
    {
    }
};

class ADer : public A
{
public:
    typedef A base_t;
};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
    }
};

class BDer : public B
{
public:
    typedef B base_t;
};

template <typename T>
void Foo()
{
    typename T::base_t x;
    // Here x will always be base class of T
}


int main()
{
    Foo<BDer>();
    Foo<ADer>();

    return 0;
}
```